# UITextView の範囲選択を取得したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

UITextView で選択した範囲をコードで取得したいです。

範囲選択を変更したときに呼び出されるメソッドなどはありますか？
また選択範囲を取得するメソッドも教えてください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

範囲選択を変更したときに呼び出されるメソッド: UITextViewDelegateプロトコルのtextViewDidChangeSelection:

選択範囲を取得するメソッド: UITextViewのselectedRangeプロパティ

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSString *selectedText = [textView.text substringWithRange:textView.selectedRange];
}
```

例えば、上記のようなコードで選択範囲が変わるたびに、選択範囲のテキストが取得できます。

Comment: delegateを設定することを忘れないでください。